# Webpack setup for non-framework project

Tags: node.js, express, webpack, bundle

How to use [Webpack](https://webpack.js.org/) for minifying my project what is built on `Express Generator`?

I mean how to bundle all js files what I have in `domain.tld/js/` and other folders automatically?

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried this for Express, but do you have a file that imports them all? If not, you can try creating a "entry-point" file that require's them. [Here](https://brian.olore.net/wp/2017/06/journey-to-webpack-part-3-finish-the-vendors/) is a more detailed description of how I did something similar recently.

In short - create a file called `file.js` and point to all your files like this:

```
import '../node_modules/modernizr/modernizr';
import '../node_modules/detectizr/dist/detectizr';
```

Then you can create your webpack.config.js with an [entry](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/entry-points/) point like this

```
const config = {
  entry: './path/to/my/entry/file.js'
};

module.exports = config;
```

This should at least get you started.